# List duplicate values from a column in a userform excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, listbox, userform

I would like to get this formula to display the unique emails in a listbox.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$F$400, $F321)>1, G321, "")
```

In a user form, the name is loaded in to label1 or textbox1 on initialize, which ever works best.
Listbox1 will display the unique emails from the duplicate value from the label1 or textbox1.
The user can select the proper email for the duplicated name from listbox1 and click a button that enters the name and the selected email on a different worksheet.

Scope: A user form is opened where a name is entered in a combobox from sheet10.range("F2:F400").
If that name is duplicated, it will open another userform to select the proper email for that name.

So, if the name Bill Gates is in `F2:F400` more than once, Bill Gates will be loaded in to label1 or textbox1 and the listbox1 will list all unique emails to that name.

```
Column F = (321) Bill Gates (322) Bill Gates (323) Bill Gates.

Column G = (321) a@email.com (322) b@email.com (323) c@email.com.
```

The userform will load "Bill Gates" into label1 or textbox1 and all the emails from column G will populate listbox1 and one can be selected. When the "Use Selected" button is pressed, it will take the name and copy it to `Sheet1.Range("D10")` and copy the selected email to `Sheet1.Range("D11")`.

Please note that more user names can be duplicated and I do not want them listed in the listbox, only the value selected in the original user form.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this for a while, I came up with this;

```
Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim c As Excel.Range

Set r = Sheets("EMAIL").Range("F2:F400")

For Each c In r.Cells
    If c = TextBox1.Value Then ListBox1.AddItem c.Offset(, 1)
        
Next c
```

I was initially over-complicating everything.

It seems to be working okay but if someone has an alternate solution or can improve on my code, please post.

Thank you for your time.